# Trying to save array of data in database using c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle, ado.net

I am trying to save array of data in database how to achieve it.

I have a form where three inputs PRODUCT_ID, TDC_NO, REVISION are there along with array list of values generated dynamically (sizeMin, sizeMax, tolMin, tolMax). I want to store those dynamically generated values in `Prop_detail` whose structure I have mentioned at below and PRODUCT_ID, TDC_NO, REVISION values in `tdcProduct1` table whose structure I designed below.how to pass those array list of values from server side to database .and how to store further in database.

.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {   
var user = {};
                user.PRODUCT_ID = 1;
                user.TDC_NO = $("[id*=Tdc_No]").val();
                user.REVISION = $("#Revision").text();
/* Creating Array object as WireDimDetails to add in user object*/
                var WireDimDetails = new Array();
                $("#WireDimTbl tbody tr").each(function () {
                    var row = $(this);
                    /* Declare and sets the WireDimDetail object with the property which will add in WireDimDetails array object*/
                    var WireDimDetail = {};
                    var sizeMin = row.find("[id^=SizeMin]").val();
                    /* Checking if control exist or not else assign empty value in sizeMax*/
                    var sizeMax = row.find("[id^=SizeMax]") != "undefined" ? row.find("[id^=SizeMax]").val() : "";
                    var tolMin = row.find("[id^=TolMin]").val();
                    var tolMax = row.find("[id^=TolMax]").val();
                    /*Sets the Values of controls */
                    WireDimDetail.SizeMin = sizeMin;
                    WireDimDetail.SizeMax = sizeMax;
                    WireDimDetail.TolMin = tolMin;
                    WireDimDetail.TolMax = tolMax;
                    /*Add WireDimDetail object in WireDimDetails Array object*/
                    WireDimDetails.push(WireDimDetail);
                })
                /*Add WireDimDetails array of object to user object*/
                user.WireDimDetails = WireDimDetails;
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TDC.aspx/SaveFrmDetails",
data: JSON.stringify({ user: user, }),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Data has been added successfully.");
                        window.location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function (response) { alert(response.responseText); }
                });
</script>
```

Server side

```
[WebMethod]    
public static void SaveFrmDetails(User user)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;

    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TDC_PRODUCT1(PRODUCT_ID,TDC_NO, REVISION) VALUES (:PRODUCT_ID,:TDC_NO,:REVISION )",con))
        { 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            List<WireDimDetail> wireDimDetails = user.WireDimDetails;

            for (int i = 0; i < wireDimDetails.Count; i++)
            {
                WireDimDetail wireDimDetail = wireDimDetails[i];
                string sizeMin = wireDimDetail.SizeMin;
                string sizeMax = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wireDimDetail.SizeMax) ? wireDimDetail.SizeMax : "0"; // set default value
                string tolMin = wireDimDetail.TolMin;
                string tolMax = wireDimDetail.TolMax;
            }

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PRODUCT_ID",user.PRODUCT_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":TDC_NO", user.TDC_NO);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":REVISION", user.REVISION);

            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Table structure for saving data and array list of data, `tdcProduct1` table consist of three columns:

```
Productid | Tdc_no | Revision
```

And second table `Prop_detail`:

```
Tdc_no | Tdc_property
```

My concern is how to store an array of data in `Prop_detail` table at the same time while storing data in `tdcProduct1` using `SaveFrmDetails`. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You want save `WireDimDetail` to `Tdc_property` for user ? is `Tdc_property` nvarchar ?

Comment: @Aria yesTdc_property is nvarchar

Comment: then see my answer and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to save multiple `WireDimDetail` to `Prop_detail` per user

so a simple way is loop through the `wireDimDetails` and get string of `wireDimDetail` for inserting in `Tdc_property`.

After inserting row in `TDC_PRODUCT1`, for inserting details the code would be like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveFrmDetails(User user)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TDC_PRODUCT1(PRODUCT_ID,TDC_NO, REVISION) VALUES (:PRODUCT_ID,:TDC_NO,:REVISION )", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PRODUCT_ID", user.PRODUCT_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":TDC_NO", user.TDC_NO);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":REVISION", user.REVISION);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Prop_detail(Tdc_no,Tdc_property) values(@tdN,@tdProp)";
            foreach (WireDimDetail wireDimDetail in user.WireDimDetails)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(wireDimDetail.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, wireDimDetail);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdN", user.TDC_NO);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdProp", stringwriter.ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

the `stringwriter` is string of each `WireDimDetail`.

but if you want to new record for `sizeMin`,`sizeMax`,`tolMin` and `tolMax` change `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach (WireDimDetail wireDimDetail in user.WireDimDetails)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    string[] strNumbers = new string[4]
    {
        wireDimDetail.SizeMin,
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wireDimDetail.SizeMax) ? wireDimDetail.SizeMax : "0",
        wireDimDetail.TolMin,
        wireDimDetail.TolMax
    };
    foreach (string number in strNumbers)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdN", user.TDC_NO);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdProp", number);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The final try would be like :

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveFrmDetails(User user)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TDC_PRODUCT1(PRODUCT_ID,TDC_NO, REVISION) VALUES (:PRODUCT_ID,:TDC_NO,:REVISION )", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PRODUCT_ID", user.PRODUCT_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":TDC_NO", user.TDC_NO);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":REVISION", user.REVISION);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Prop_detail(Tdc_no,Rowno,Prop_Name,Tdc_property) values(@tdN,@rowNo,@propN,@tdProp)";
            int rowNum = 1;// You can get rowNum from DB and initiate it to last rowNum
            foreach (WireDimDetail wireDimDetail in user.WireDimDetails)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                Dictionary<string, string> strNumbers = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                    {
                    {"sizMin",  wireDimDetail.SizeMin },
                    {"sizeMax" , !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wireDimDetail.SizeMax) ? wireDimDetail.SizeMax.ToString() : "0" },
                    {"tolMin",   wireDimDetail.TolMin.ToString() },
                    {"tolMax",   wireDimDetail.TolMax.ToString() }
                    }; 
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in strNumbers)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdN", user.TDC_NO);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowNo", rowNum);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@propN", kvp.Key);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdProp", kvp.Value);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                rowNum++;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTES:**

1- `rowNum` can be retrieved from DB and then increase (can be initiated by `select max(rowNo) from Prop_detail`).

2- I used dictionary to hold the name of variable such as `sizeMax` and etc, there are many ways to do this

Comment: do i need to use above code same inside SaveFrmDetails method after  inserting row in TDC_PRODUCT1.

Comment: thx a lot .but it is saved in xml format in one column in database and i want it to be store in sequence wise so that i can query.and how would i show it again browser.

Comment: what do you mean about sequence can you give more clarify, pleas show me what you want exactly.

Comment: i mean data should be store in Tdc_no | Tdc_property,7y|2.0, 7y|3.4, 7y|9.8, 7y|9.5 in this below format one below other respectively.

Comment: Okay, then which prop of `WireDimDetail` have `2.0` or `9.8` or `9.5`, I think you want to create rows for user one for `sizeMin`, one for `sizeMax`, one for `tolMin` and one for `tolMax` yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162325/discussion-between-hari-and-aria).